# FirebaseJob Dispatcher: How to specify the number of retries in job with RETRY_POLICY_EXPONENTIAL

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-job-dispatcher

How to specify the number of retries in job with retry type **RETRY_POLICY_EXPONENTIAL**, below is my code

```
    val job: Job =dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            .setTag("mytesttag")
            .setService(MyJobService::class.java)
            .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
            .build()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, it can be done using **FirebaseJobDispatcher** **instance**, Like this

```
        var job = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                .setTag("mytesttag")
                .setService(MyJobService::class.java)
                .setRetryStrategy(dispatcher.newRetryStrategy(                        
                 RetryStrategy.RETRY_POLICY_EXPONENTIAL,30,300))
                .build()
```